# Can I add option menu in Dialog?

Tags: android

I want to add option menu on my Dialog . I try this .But my option menu is displayed on layout not on dialog .How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that if you create an Activity with Theme Dialog. but still Menu will be Shown below the Screen since thats how a menu can be shown. if you want it to be on Dialog, then create Activity with Dialog theme, add a ListView and override `onKeyDown()` method to show a list of options when menu button is pressed.